# Cannot install a Windows store app for all users : The current system configuration does not support the installation of this package

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app, winget

I'm trying to install [this Windows Store app](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/nvidia-control-panel/9NF8H0H7WMLT) on Windows 10 for all users :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winget install --accept-package-agreements --id 9NF8H0H7WMLT --scope machine
The `msstore` source requires that you view the following agreements before using.
Terms of Transaction: https://aka.ms/microsoft-store-terms-of-transaction
The source requires the current machine's 2-letter geographic region to be sent to the backend service to function properly (ex. "US").

Do you agree to all the source agreements terms?
[Y] Yes  [N] No: Y
Found NVIDIA Control Panel [9NF8H0H7WMLT] Version Unknown
This package is provided through Microsoft Store. winget may need to acquire the package from Microsoft Store on behalf of the current user.
Agreements for NVIDIA Control Panel [9NF8H0H7WMLT] Version Unknown
Version: Unknown
Publisher: NVIDIA Corp.
Description: Featuring display management, application, and gaming-specific features, the NVIDIA Control Panel ensures the best overall experience using NVIDIA graphics
License: ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9NF8H0H7WMLT
Privacy Url: https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/privacy-center/
Agreements:
Category: Utilities & tools
Pricing: Free
Free Trial: No
Terms of Transaction: https://aka.ms/microsoft-store-terms-of-transaction
Seizure Warning: https://aka.ms/microsoft-store-seizure-warning
Store License Terms: https://aka.ms/microsoft-store-license


Starting package install...
The current system configuration does not support the installation of this package.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

But it fails with this error message :

```
The current system configuration does not support the installation of this package.
```

EDIT0 : Cannot find the version of that package either :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winget show --id 9NF8H0H7WMLT --versions
Found NVIDIA Control Panel [9NF8H0H7WMLT]
Version
-------
Unknown
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Winget might be getting the wrong version. Try to install it via the Microsoft Store.

Comment: @harrymc How do I install with the Microsoft Store for ALL users ?

Comment: You can't, unless you use the [Microsoft Store for Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store) which isn't your case. I wonder why the users are missing the NVIDIA Control Panel, if the full package has been installed.